# Dealing with multiple definitions of the same symbol in different compilation units

Tags: c++, include, preprocessor

In order to use `volk.h`, symbol `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` needs to be defined in exactly one compilation unit.

I have three files, `main.cpp`, `application.cpp` and `application.h`

Here's `main.cpp`:

```
#include "application.h"

#include <stdexcept>

int main(int, char*[]) {
    Application application;
    try {
        application.run();
    } catch (std::runtime_error e) {
        printf("%s/n", e.what());
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the topmost part of `application.h` (this is the only file where `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` appears):

```
#pragma once

#pragma warning(push, 0)
#define VK_ENABLE_BETA_EXTENSIONS
#define VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "volk.h"
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Finally, `application.cpp` only includes `application.h` on the very top and not much else matters anyway.

The code above doesn't compile. It claims certain volk symbols have already been defined. If I remove `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` from application.h, then it doesn't compile because symbols aren't defined at all.

However, if I move the volk inclusion to `main.cpp`, everything works. However, I don't need volk in main and I don't want to include it there.

Why does this happen?

Is `main.cpp` one compilation unit and `application.h/cpp` the other, but since `application.h` is included in `main.cpp` does it get added to both units, thus adding `volk.h` twice with `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` defined? How does one deal with this?

Every time I think I figured the include system out, something like this happens.

Comment: Don't you want to move `#define VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` to `application.cpp` (before #including `application.h`)?

Comment: Well, both `main.cpp` and `application.cpp` include the header file which defines `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION`, so both of these translation units define it. And you acknowledged that you understand that only one translation unit should define it. So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I was looking for some kind of sane solution and  Paul Sanders has given ti to me. I also wasn't 100% sure my assumption was correct. Do you want to make an official answer, or do I delete the question or do I just leave it unanswered?